# How to clean or resize the ibtmp1 file in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, mysql-5.7

MySQL 5.7 introduces a new file **ibtmp1** for storing temporary data in InnoDB to increase the performance.

But I have noted that its size increases continuously. On my db server its sizes increases to 92GB.

Is there any way of reducing size or deleting the file **without restarting the server** ?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly useful: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136627/managing-ibtmp1-file-growth-on-mysql-5-7

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This solution required restart, and I can't afford downtime.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am looking a solution to resolve this without service restart because in my case this file increases very rapidly..

Comment: I upvoted your question, this is as much as I can do at the moment.  I hope you get an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , No problem...  Thanks

Comment: (Not an immediate solution)  I suggest you look critically at the queries that need huge tmp tables.  Good queries with good indexes won't chew up 92GB of tmp.

Comment: Also, long-running queries can chew up tmp space due to saving undo stuff.

Comment: If you must restart, look into saving and reloading the buffer_pool.  This should decrease the restart time.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The **ibtmp1** once created can't be shrink by any method without restarting mysql service.

There are two ways to handle it:

**Precaution** : At the time of server start you should limit the size of this file as:

```
 innodb_temp_data_file_path = ibtmp1:12M:autoextend:max:5G
```

where max 5G means this file size limits to 5GB.

**Cure**  :  If file already created you need to restart service:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;
Shutdown MySQL
remove ibtmp1
start MySQL.
```

Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-temporary-tablespace.html

Comment: Running AWS RDS MySQL 5.7, a "failover-with-reboot" was sufficient to truncate this file.

Comment: this question was particular for native mysql not for cloud.

Comment: Mini-Tutorial: Edit file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`. Add as last line: `innodb_temp_data_file_path = ibtmp1:12M:autoextend:max:5G` (or xG). Restart Mysql: `sudo service mysql restart` --- Check the file size at `/var/lib/mysql/ibtmp1`.

Comment: I found it was unnecessary to remove ibtmp1, the file was resized when I restarted the mysql service. Ver 14.14

Comment: @JonHulka the question is how to remove if you can't restart - So precaution is better than cure..

Comment: @AmanAggarwal Precaution works both ways. I was erring on the side of doing as little as possible to mess with how MySQL manages its data - it probably makes no difference. I've had a bad experience in the past moving ib* files around. I didn't have to restart the server, just the MySQL service.

Answer (score 10):

In mysql 5.7 and higher all you need to do to reclaim the space used by the ibtmp1 file is **restart the service**.

You **do not** have to set **GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;** or manually delete the file.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem just do the following steps:

1- run this command:
`sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

2- Add the following row under [mysqld] row 
`innodb_temp_data_file_path = ibtmp1:12M:autoextend:max:5G`

3- Save the file.

4- Now we need to free up some disk space and delete ibtmp1, we can do that by restarting the SQL server:

`sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: It appears to me that this setting can cause temporary table creation to fail, if the 5G limit is exceeded.